# Hugo layouts split h3 content to div

Tags: javascript, hugo

I wonder how to modify content of simple test.md file to generate .html with hugo by following manner - Every h3 (###) and all code ahead put into , until next h3. Simply speaking, I would like to split each h3 section to seperate tab, with title same as h3 tag.

test.md file looks like this:

```
---
title: "Some title"
layout: test
---


## Title

### some content
lorem ipsum 1

### some content 2
lorem ipsum 2

### some content 3
lorem ipsum 3
```

And the desired hugo output looks like following:

```
<h2 id="title">Title</h1>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab" id="some content">
    <h3 id="some-content">some content</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="some content">
    <h3 id="some-content-2">some content 2</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="some content">
    <h3 id="some-content-3">some content 3</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If possible I would like to create this using Hugo templates but some javascript trick is also acceptable. Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar feature to implement (with Hugo only, no javascript), and I had to define a [Hugo **partial template**](https://gohugo.io/templates/partials/) in my theme:

In `themes/mytheme/layouts/partials/boxtext.html`:

```
{{ $paragraphs := split .Content "<h2 " }}

{{ range $index, $p := $paragraphs }}
    {{ $pp := trim $p " \n" }}
    {{ if (eq $index 0) }}
        {{ printf "%s\n" $pp | safeHTML }}
    {{ end }}
    {{ if and (ne $pp "") (gt $index 0) }}
    <div class="boxtext">
        {{ printf "<h2 %s\n" $pp | safeHTML }}
    </div>
    {{ end }}
{{end}}
```

(This is not to do the same output as you want: adapt it to your case, beginning with `split .Content "<h3 "` instead of `h2`!)

Actually, to be sure if did not generate extra-line and remain compact, I had to rewrite it as:

```
{{ $paragraphs := split .Content "<h2 " }}{{ range $index, $p := $paragraphs }}{{ $pp := trim $p " \n" }}{{ if (eq $index 0) }}{{ printf "%s\n" $pp | safeHTML }}{{ end }}{{ if and (ne $pp "") (gt $index 0) }}    <div class="boxtext">
        {{ printf "<h2 %s\n" $pp | safeHTML }}
    </div>{{ end }}{{end}}
```

Then my `single.html` template page the relevant section of my site could wrap the HTML code produced with: `{{ partial "boxtext.html" . }}`

As in:

```
> cat "themes/mytheme/layouts/mysection/single.html"
{{ define "main" }}

<body id="id1">
    <div id="top">
        <ul class="menu">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>{{ range .Resources }}{{ if .RelPermalink }}
      <li>azza2<a href="{{ .RelPermalink }}">{{ .ResourceType | title }}</a></li>{{ else }}
      <li>{{ .ResourceType | title }} (no link, only embedded in page)</li>{{ end }}{{ end }}
    </div>
    {{ partial "boxtext.html" . }}
</body>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. I want to - for only one subpage - split my content into 2 parts and insert some javascript calculator in between. I managed to insert the calculator at the bottom or before the {{.Content}} but not in between. help appreciated! :)