# How to properly organize content in Hugo without abusing layouts?

Tags: web, hugo, organization

I’m trying to figure out what is the proper way of organizing content in Hugo. I have read the documentation but I still don’t understand what is the right way of going about this.

I understand the concept of having content and layout directories and using .md files to provide article-like content to a page.

However, if I want to build a typical web page where I have multiple sections, how do I do that without abusing layouts directory?

Here is an example:

```
<section class="bg-red">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porta quam at auctor tincidunt. Proin tempus nec arcu at scelerisque. Aliquam aliquam bibendum enim, eu hendrerit ex iaculis ac. Morbi lectus neque, dictum a magna nec, commodo feugiat erat. Donec sit amet urna arcu. Vivamus ullamcorper, metus at imperdiet blandit, urna eros hendrerit turpis, quis mollis neque purus a nulla. In ut neque ante. Donec nec libero pulvinar, accumsan neque et, blandit ligula.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porta quam at auctor tincidunt. Proin tempus nec arcu at scelerisque. Aliquam aliquam bibendum enim, eu hendrerit ex iaculis ac. Morbi lectus neque, dictum a magna nec, commodo feugiat erat. Donec sit amet urna arcu. Vivamus ullamcorper, metus at imperdiet blandit, urna eros hendrerit turpis, quis mollis neque purus a nulla. In ut neque ante. Donec nec libero pulvinar, accumsan neque et, blandit ligula.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="bg-blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Second section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porta quam at auctor tincidunt. Proin tempus nec arcu at scelerisque. Aliquam aliquam bibendum enim, eu hendrerit ex iaculis ac. Morbi lectus neque, dictum a magna nec, commodo feugiat erat. Donec sit amet urna arcu. Vivamus ullamcorper, metus at imperdiet blandit, urna eros hendrerit turpis, quis mollis neque purus a nulla. In ut neque ante. Donec nec libero pulvinar, accumsan neque et, blandit ligula.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="./random_image.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

...
```

It is a typical website page consisting of different sections. Markdown file is okay as long as you have a continious article-like text that gets rendered in a layout page.

How do I organize this properly with Hugo withoug having everyting in the layout file?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428130/hugo-layouts-split-h3-content-to-div?rq=2), which splits your content on h3 tags. You can also make every nugget of content its own .md file in a section that is not served (by using empty single.html and list.html files) and range over them in your layout. Finally you can also introduce your own splitting character (my favorite solution).